# java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: classpath from tomcat after spring boot upgrade

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot

I upgraded my project on Spring Boot from 2.0.0.M7 to 2.0.1, and my ssl configuration have broken. 
I had my keystore/truststore in resources catalog, and properties in application.yml which pointed to them.

application.yml

```
server:
  schema: "https"
  address: "localhost"
  port: 8080
  sslPort: 8443
  servlet:
    session:
      timeout: 900

spring:
  profiles:
    active: dev

ssl:
  keystoreFile: classpath:.keystore
  keystorePass: ****
  truststoreFile: classpath:.truststore
  truststorePass: ****
```

I use properties to build ssl connector in my @Configuration class.
sslProperties object here contains all properties from ssl section of application.yml from above.

```
private Connector createSslConnector(WebServerProperties webServerProperties, SslProperties sslProperties) {
    Connector connector = new Connector("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol");
    Http11NioProtocol protocol = (Http11NioProtocol) connector.getProtocolHandler();

    connector.setScheme(WebServerProperties.HTTPS_SCHEMA);
    connector.setSecure(true);
    connector.setPort(webServerProperties.getSslPort());

    protocol.setSSLEnabled(true);
    protocol.setKeystoreFile(sslProperties.getKeystoreFile());
    protocol.setKeystorePass(sslProperties.getKeystorePass());
    protocol.setKeyPass(sslProperties.getKeyPass());
    protocol.setKeyAlias(sslProperties.getKeyAlias());
    protocol.setCiphers(sslProperties.getCiphers());
    protocol.setSslEnabledProtocols(sslProperties.getSslProtocols());

    return connector;
}
```

After upgrade, application doesn't start with following exception

```
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8443]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:549)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:367)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:107)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:86)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:409)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:174)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:179)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:152)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:544)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:137)
    at net.twisteddna.Application.main(Application.java:37)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:995)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown protocol: classpath
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:116)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:87)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:225)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:1086)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.init(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:268)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:581)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.init(AbstractHttp11Protocol.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:993)
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: classpath
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:600)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:490)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:439)
    at java.net.URI.toURL(URI.java:1089)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.file.ConfigFileLoader.getInputStream(ConfigFileLoader.java:95)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getStore(SSLUtilBase.java:132)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLHostConfigCertificate.getCertificateKeystore(SSLHostConfigCertificate.java:204)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSEUtil.getKeyManagers(JSSEUtil.java:184)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:114)
    ... 27 common frames omitted
```

Spring Boot 2.0.0.M7 contained tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23, where AbstractHttp11Protocol is.
And Spring Boot 2.0.1 has tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.
And newer tomcat version seems to forget how to read from classpath

Comment: You cannot use `classpath` prefix for that as those aren't loaded by Spring but through tomcat.

Comment: But the same code and configuration works for Spring Boot 2.0.0.M7 version, and throws this exception in 2.0.1
So how should I properly reference resources to load it to tomcat?

Comment: Remove `classpath`. That it worked in a milestone doesn't mean it still works in the final also the resource is loaded by tomcat and not Spring hence the Sprng resource loading rules don't apply.